# Windows detects two monitors, but no display

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently decided that I would connect a second monitor to my PC. I realised that my graphics card had a VGA and a DVI input and given the fact that both my monitors are equipped with VGA cables, I got myself a VGA to DVI adapter (VGA to DVI-I (Dual Link) to be more specific), however, while the monitor connected to the DVI port through the VGA to DVI adapter is getting detected, it does not display anything and acts as if there is no input.

Secondly, I am actually unsure whether my graphics card has a DVI-I (Dual Link) or DVI-D (Dual Link) input, considering the holes differentiating DVI-I from DVI-D look like they've been forced in there (can be seen on attached pictures).

Am I doing something wrong and can it be a software problem?

And if my input happens to be a DVI-D input, can a DVI-I stick work together with a DVI-D input?

**What I HAVE tried:**

- Updating Graphics Card drivers
- Restarting my PC
- Updating Graphics Card drivers
- Resetting both monitors to factory settings
- Switching between monitors plugged in through the VGA to DVI adapter
  (same effect, the monitor plugged in through the normal VGA port
  worked, the other got detected [even by name] but did not show any
  display.)

**PC and Monitor specifications:**

Operating system = Windows 7 Home Premium - Service Pack 1

Motherboard =  MSI 760GM-P21(FX) (MS-7641) 3.0

Graphics = NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650 - GDDR5 - 1024 MBytes

Monitor 1 = HP L1925

Monitor 2 = PHILIPS 170S4

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check display settings (right click on Desktop, select Screen Resolution) to make sure that your computer is seeing two monitors, and if so what happens if you set the Multiple Displays drop-down to "Extend these displays"?

Comment: The screen goes black for a few seconds but then nothing changes. The second screen is active (I can move my mouse outside the first monitor) and I can see the second monitor in my Screen Resolution settings and Nvidia panel, where everything implies that there should be no problems.

Comment: Have you ensured that you're using inputs from the graphics card only? If you try to use an input from the graphics card and the mobo, you might run into issues there.

Comment: Yes, I only connect them to the 2 inputs shown on the pictures, both are from the graphics card.

Comment: I know this will sound strange but try a different DVI adapter! Sometimes they get defective with no apparent reason.

Comment: @Genesis_GDK This would require me to buy another adapter, which I would prefer to stay away from doing (will do eventually if no other solution is found of course), but thanks. Are you able to tell from my pictures whether my graphics card's input is a DVI-I or DVI-D input? And would a DVI-I stick be able to work with a DVI-D input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that one of my monitors had a DVI-I input, meaning I could test my adapter's viability by testing how it works the other way (VGA from PC into DVI-I on my monitor). It turns out it works perfectly when I do that, meaning the only possible reason to why all this happens, is that the output on my PC is in fact a DVI-D output, and the holes on the left side were made with hand by someone else, probably thinking that a DVI-I stick would work as long as the holes were there.

Comment: That, unfortunately, is why some people should not be allowed near computers... if the cable doesn't fit - with very little pressure by hand - then chances are it's the wrong connector and further pressure will damage the connector or socket!

Comment: @Big Chris Yeah, I hope it isn't damaged to the point where it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card has got a DVI-I input and you have a DVI-I adapter judging from the picture.

A  DVI-I adapter cannot fit into a  DVI-D input so that gives you another clue as to what type of configuration you have.

The DVI-I output is VGA compatible which ensures that your PC monitor should work with a VGA cable and a DVI adapter.

Since the monitor is picked up but does not work, I would suggest you try the solutions below.

1) Either get yourself a DVI cable to test the Graphics card output with the monitor (if the monitor has a DVI input)

2) Try replacing the DVI adapter.

I had an identical setup to yours and my troubleshooting ended in me buying a new DVI adapter.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your help, even though you weren't right it made me think and lead me to the right answer in the end. I solved it :)